# Is there a hdaps extension of gnome shell?

Tags: thinkpad

hdaps is a hard disk protect implement in thinkpad T and W series.
My computer is thinkpad W500.
How to use hdaps in gnome shell ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

hdaps isn't anything to do with the user interface. Install `hdapsd` for protection.

Comment: In gnome 2 , I can install hdaps applet in gnome panel.

Comment: Or maybe he's referring to something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mr9jHa26WX8